# Case Statement gives always 1. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view, case

I'm having a problem with `CASE` statement in MYSQL. It always gives me 1.

Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    a VARCHAR(200),
    b VARCHAR(200),
    c VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (a)
);
CREATE TABLE B (
    a VARCHAR(200),
    d VARCHAR(200),
    e VARCHAR(200)
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A(a)
);
```

So i'm making a simple join on `A` and `B` like this:

```
CREATE VIEW C AS (
SELECT
         a,
         b,
         CASE
             WHEN '0' THEN '0'
             WHEN '1' THEN '1'
             WHEN 'WEEKDAY' THEN '0'
             WHEN 'WEEKEND' THEN '1'
             ELSE ''
         END AS c,
         d,
         e
FROM
    B
RIGHT OUTER JOIN A ON
    B.a = A.a
);
```

When I tried to get my data on this view `c` is always `1`. Even if in the orignal table `B` it is set to `1` or `WEEKDAY`.

Why is my `CASE WHEN THEN` statement isn't working as I expect, what did I miss?

Comment: CASE for which column to compare ?

Comment: Just look at the first line of the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have done something strange.  You don't have any comparisons.  I assume you intend:

```
     (CASE <COLUMN NAME GOES HERE!!!>
         WHEN '0' THEN '0'
         WHEN '1' THEN '1'
         WHEN 'WEEKDAY' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'WEEKEND' THEN '1'
         ELSE ''
      END) AS c,
```

It is unclear which column name, though.

I would normally write this as:

```
(case when <column> in ('0', 'WEEKDAY') then '0'
      when <column> in ('1', 'WEEKEND') then '1'
      else <column>
 end) as c
```

I find it easier to maintain the lists when the destination value is all in one place.

The `as c` gives the name for the expression.  However, the logic in the expression is entirely independent of the name given.  So, I would recommend:

```
(case when c in ('0', 'WEEKDAY') then '0'
      when c in ('1', 'WEEKEND') then '1'
      else c
 end) as c
```

Of course, you don't want another column named `c` in the result set.

Comment: Ho wow! I thought the `AS` was giving the name... So i can remove the `AS c` and replace `CASE` by `CASE c`?

Comment: @BeGreen you should still include a column name

Comment: You example is wonderful.I'll keep this format for the rest of my life!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW C AS (
SELECT
         a,
         b,
         CASE C
             WHEN '0' THEN '0'
             WHEN '1' THEN '1'
             WHEN 'WEEKDAY' THEN '0'
             WHEN 'WEEKEND' THEN '1'
             ELSE ''
         END AS c,
         d,
         e
FROM
    B
RIGHT OUTER JOIN A ON
    B.a = A.a
);
```